# Show that $y=5x-\frac{6}{x}$ if $y$ is the sum of two numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $y$ is the sum of two numbers, of which the first varies directly and the second inversely as $x$, and if $y=7$, when $x=2$, and $y=-1$, when $x=1$, show that $y=5x-\frac{6}{x}$

"If $y$ is the sum of two numbers, of which the first varies directly and the second inversely as $x$":

$y=ax+\frac{b}{x}$

$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
7=2a+\frac{b}{2} \\ 
-1=a+b \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$
$\Rightarrow$
$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
7=2a+\frac{b}{2} \\ 
-2=2a+2b \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$
$\Rightarrow 9=\frac{b}{2}-2b$

$18=-3b$

$b=-6, a=5$ which is $y=5x-\frac{6}{x}$.

My question is if I had set up  $y=ax+\frac{x}{b}$:

$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
7=2a+\frac{2}{b} \\ 
-1=a+\frac{1}{b} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$
$\Rightarrow$
$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
7=2a+\frac{2}{b} \\ 
-2=2a+\frac{2}{b} \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$
$\Rightarrow$
$9=0$

Which is a nonsensical answer. So when it says "varies inversely as $x$", does this mean $x$ is strictly restricted to being in the denominator or is this problem just worded poorly? Becuase I feel $x$ being in the numerator also means "varies inversely as $x$".
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Note that if $c=\frac{1}{b}$, then $c$ would also be constant, with your equation then becoming $y=ax+cx=(a+c)x$, i.e., $y$ varies directly with $x$ in the second number as well, and $y$ varies directly overall as $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $\frac{6}{x}$ gets smaller as $x$ gets larger, so $\frac{6}{x}$ varies $\it inversely$ with respect to $x$. However, the number $\frac{x}{b}$ (where $b$ is fixed) gets larger as $x$ gets larger, so  $\frac{x}{b}$ varies $\it directly$ with respect to $x$.